# Can my familiar use the bonus attack from two-weapon fighting to make its own attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, familiars

Two weapon fighting:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand. -PHB 195

Pact of the chain feature:

> Additionally, when you take the Attack action, you can forgo one of your own attacks to allow your familiar to make one attack of its own. -PHB 107

If I attack with a short sword, can I direct my familiar to make an attack in place of my second bonus-action attack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No.**

If you have enough Fighter levels, you get more than one attack from your Attack Action, so could forfeit one to let your Familiar attack, and use the rest yourself.

Fighter's Extra Attack feature: (PBR 25)

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of
>   once, **whenever you take the Attack action** on your turn.

But, two-weapon fighting doesn't give you extra attacks **as part of an Attack Action**, it gives you an attack as a Bonus Action. And, you don't get that Bonus Action unless you attack with your other hand first.

Two-Weapon Fighting: (PBR 74)

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light
>   melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can
>   **use a bonus action** to attack with a different light melee
>   weapon that you’re holding in the other hand.

Bonus actions: (PBR 69)

> You can take a bonus
>   action only when a special ability, spell, or other feature
>   of the game states that you can do something as a bonus
>   action. You otherwise don’t have a bonus action to take.

*(Quotes are from [Player's Basic Rules](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules) v0.2)*

Comment: I think the key part in the p74 bit you've quoted is actually where it says "take the Attack action **and attack with a light melee weapon**" - as opposed to "take the attack action and let your familiar attack instead".

Comment: Alright, it makes me sad, but this answer makes unfortunate sense. Shenanigans thwarted.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do this. Just as it says, you can forgo one of your own attacks to allow your familiar to make an attack **when you take the Attack action**, not when you use a bonus action to attack with two-weapon fighting.

Two-weapon fighting does not allow you to make an extra attack with the Attack action - it allows you to make an extra attack with a bonus action. It's a separate action, and your familiar can only replace attacks made with the Attack action.

Comment: Just as an addendum: Bonus actions are not something that you *have* to *spend* but rather a special action you can only do when called for, and only once per round. So you can't swap two actions just because they are Bonus Actions. They aren't measured of time or speed like Moves and Standards.

Answer (score -6):

Now this might be considered to be weaselly, or min/maxy, but what you *can* do (which is close to equivalent) is to take the Attack action as your full action, and forgo that attack to allow your familiar to attack, but still since you took the Attack action, you can then use your bonus action to attack with your offhand second weapon.  So it works out pretty similar, just that your actual swing is with your second weapon, not the first.

Comment: You can not do this. See the "and attack with a light melee weapon" In the Two Weapon Fighting text.

Comment: That's there to be a limit, not allowing you to attack with a weapon that isn't light.  Like a number of things that have come up recently, it isn't definitive and there are a couple of ways to rule it.  And apparently some people cannot stand that a DM might do it differently than they do.  I would require the character to have a light weapon in each hand ready to attack, but would allow the main action to be forgone in favor of the familiar.

Comment: I don't care how people rule at their tables, I care about what the rules say. And they say 100% clearly, that you need to actually attack with the weapon. I don't see at all how that is "not definitive".  "take the Attack action **and attack with a light melee weapon**" are the prerequisites for tow weapon fighting.

Comment: You misunderstand. I am not trying to critizise you or whatever you think, I'm simply trying to understand your point on how that is not 100% clear. I might simply be mistaken, and if I was, I would accept that. I am not a native speaker after all, but I consider myself to have a relatively good grasp on the english language. And maybe I should have said it in another way: "I care about what the rules say, at least in the context of a question on Stack Exchange that is asking about the rules".

Comment: The text requires that the creature attack with a light melee weapon to gain the bonus action, not that they use an attack action while holding a light melee weapon.

Comment: My point, which keeps coming up, is that way too many people are way too hung up on tiny little rules quirks.  The point of it being light weapons is so that you can't two-weapon fight with bigger weapons (unless you take the feat for that).  I would have worded it as "take the Attack action and be wielding a light melee weapon".  Either way, it isn't any kind of game-breaking unbalanced power to let someone with two light weapons have his familiar attack substitute for one of those attacks instead of having to lose both of them for that.

Comment: More generally, I'm finding it kind of irritating that someone asks a question, and I say "It could be A or B; I like B, but some people will rule A", which acknowledges the controversy and doesn't try to push anything on anybody, and instead of other people responding with "I like and would rule for A in this case", I get a bunch of downvotes and arguments about "It's A, and anyone who thinks otherwise is wrong!  You may not even consider B!".   That's just rude.

Comment: The reason simply is that A is what the rules say but B is not. You are of course free to use B as a house rule at your table but the op here clearly wanted an answer according to the official rules and not house rule alternatives.