# Can the attack granted by the Gloom Stalker Ranger's Stalker's Flurry be forgone by features such as the Battle Master Fighter's Commander's Strike?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, ranger, action-economy

This is inspired by the following two related questions:

- [Can my familiar use the bonus attack from two-weapon fighting to make its own attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62355)
- [Can you use Commander's Strike to forgo an attack granted by Horde Breaker?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74248)

Notably, the features in question (Warlock's [Pact of the Chain Pact Boon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#ClassFeatures) and Battle Master Fighter's Commander's Strike) both allow you to forgo an attack after taking the Attack action:

> [...] Additionally, when you take the Attack action, you can forgo one of your own attacks to allow your familiar to make one attack with its reaction.

> [...] When you take the Attack action on your turn, you can forgo one of your attacks and use a bonus action to direct one of your companions to strike. [...]

And the other features asked about (Two-Weapon Fighting and the Hunter Ranger's Horde Breaker feature) both grant an additional attack that is *not* part of the Attack action:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand. [...]

> Once on each of your turns when you make a weapon attack, you can make another attack with the same weapon [...]

The answers to those questions do not all agree, and part of their differences lies in the fact that these additional attacks are *not* part of the Attack action, which are exactly the type of attacks I would now like to ask about. A particular example would be the Gloom Stalker Ranger's Stalker's Flurry feature, which states (emphasis mine):

> [...] Once on each of your turns when you miss with a weapon attack, you can make another weapon attack **as part of the same action.**

How does *this* feature interact with things like Commander's Strike and Pact of the Chain? Can the additional attack be forgone by these features?

Answer (score 2):

So the discussion in the examples you provide seem to revolve around the intention of the wording of:

> When you take the Attack action

and whether or not this means the forgone attack must be explicitly part of the attack action or could be a byproduct of taking it.

The good news is that in your quandry, the attack in question *is explicitly stated* to be part of the same attack action as you have highlighted. So even taking the strict interpretation of the rules, assuming the attack must be part of the attack action and not from it, lets do a quick checklist to see if everything works.

You take the attack action and miss with one of the attacks provided by that action.  Stalker's Flurry kicks in and provides you with an additional attack.

> Commander's Strike:
>  When you take the Attack action on your turn...

Did we take the attack action? Yes! ✔️

> Commander's Strike:
>  ...you can forgo one of your attacks...

From this attack action, do we have an attack which we can forgo? Yes! ✔️ 
 Is this attack explicitly from the attack action?

> Stalker's Fury:
>  ...you can make another weapon attack as part of the same action.

Yes!✔️

> Commander's Strike:
>  ...and use a bonus action to direct one of your companions to strike.

Do we have a bonus action still? Let's assume Yes! ✔️
 This is actually an important footnote.  Stalker's Fury can be used on bonus action or reaction attacks too and in those cases, you would not be able to use 'Commanders Strike' for multiple reasons.

### So RAW, the extra attack from the Gloom Stalker Ranger's 'Stalker's Fury' can be forgone for abilities like 'Commander's Strike' or other similarly worded abilities provided you are taking Attack action.